# Onchange capture data-price from the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Everyone onchange I want to capture the selected data-price from the dropdown option

```
<select class="tmcp-field hotel support-layer-thickness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_10" data-price="" data-rules="" data-original-rules="" id="tmcp_select_44" tabindex="44" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="Select Thickness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="" data-tm-tooltip-html="" >Select Thickness</option>
    <option value="4_1" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="8000" data-tm-tooltip-html="" >4</option>
    <option value="5_2" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="10000" data-tm-tooltip-html="" >5</option>
    <option value="6_3" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="12000" data-tm-tooltip-html="" >6</option>   
</select>
```

How can I get the data-price value

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [`jQuery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to `get/set` data associated with the specified element
- Use [`option:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to get `selected` option

```js
$('#tmcp_select_44').on('change', function() {
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
  console.log(option.data('price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tmcp-field hotel support-layer-thickness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_10" data-price="" data-rules="" data-original-rules="" id="tmcp_select_44" tabindex="44" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="Select Thickness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="" data-tm-tooltip-html="">Select Thickness</option>
  <option value="4_1" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="8000" data-tm-tooltip-html="">4</option>
  <option value="5_2" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="10000" data-tm-tooltip-html="">5</option>
  <option value="6_3" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-imagep="" data-price="12000" data-tm-tooltip-html="">6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: here is is wordking fine but in my code it's returning [object object] any idea..

Comment: @websmentor.com — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)